# jQuery disable parent trigger when clicking on child

Tags: jquery

On a website I have a div which is a click zone. When clicking in this zone, a modal should open and a video URL must be entered in the modal. Clicking on OK, the video is added to a list, that is also inside the click zone.

Now when clicking somewhere on a "white" space, the modal should open again. But clicking on the image (or delete link), should not open the modal. Unfortunately the click event on the main div gets always triggered.

I've tried to fix this with `event.stopPropagation()`, but in the way I'm using it, I can't get this work. How will I be able to achieve this.

The code snippet is a simplification of what I'm doing. Just click in the click zone and click on 'Add'. This will add an image to the click zone. You can continue doing this. But clicking on an image or delete should not open the modal. Clicking on delete should trigger the delete action.

```js
var $videoModal = $('#videoModal');
var $videoSrc = $('#video-src');
var $videoSortable = $('#videoSortable');
var $videoModalOk = $('#videoModalOK');

$('.video-clickzone').click(function() {
  $videoModal.modal('show');
});

$videoModalOk.click(function() {
  $videoSortable.append("<li id='lyON3M9P3eU'><img src='http://img.youtube.com/vi/lyON3M9P3eU/0.jpg' width='200' data-video='https://www.youtube.com/embed/lyON3M9P3eU'><div class='text-center' data-video-delete='lyON3M9P3eU'>Delete</div></li>");
  $videoModal.modal('hide');
  $('.ck-message').hide();
});
$('[data-video-delete]').click(function(e) {
  $('#' + $(this).data('video-delete')).remove();
});
```

```css
.video-clickzone {
  min-height: 150px;
  border: 2px dashed #dddddd;
  background: white;
  padding: 20px 20px;
}
.video-clickzone:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.video-clickzone .ck-message {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2em 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="video-clickzone">
  <div class="ck-message">
    <div>
      <i class="fa fa-video-camera fa-5x"></i>
    </div>
    Click to add video
  </div>

  <ul id="videoSortable" class="list-unstyled list-inline"></ul>

</div>

<div class="modal bs-example-modal-md" id="videoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header bg-primary">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Add video</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>This is just an example, click on 'Add'</p>
        <div class="form-group" id="video-form">
          <label class="control-label" for="video-src">Video URL</label>
          <input type="url" id="video-src" class="form-control">
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="videoModalOK" data-actie="">Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach an event to when the images are clicked, you can insert them when you are building the image html or as it is in my snippet, you can use jQuery on event and bind all clicks on the images. Basically you attach all clicks to li selectors inside your video image container and in that event you fire event.stopPropagation to prevent the bubble event therefore the click does not reaches the div. Notice that this will trigger the same event if you clicked on the image or on the link, so you would probably want to create different selectors in the dom (one for the image and one for the delete link) so you can handle easier the delete event.

```js
var $videoModal = $('#videoModal');
var $videoSrc = $('#video-src');
var $videoSortable = $('#videoSortable');
var $videoModalOk = $('#videoModalOK');

$('.video-clickzone').click(function() {
  $videoModal.modal('show');
});

// This is the new function
$('.video-clickzone').on("click", "li", function(evt){  
  evt.stopPropagation();
  evt.preventDefault();
})
// end of new code

$videoModalOk.click(function() {
  $videoSortable.append("<li id='lyON3M9P3eU'><img src='http://img.youtube.com/vi/lyON3M9P3eU/0.jpg' width='200' data-video='https://www.youtube.com/embed/lyON3M9P3eU'><div class='text-center' data-video-delete='lyON3M9P3eU'>Delete</div></li>");
  $videoModal.modal('hide');
  $('.ck-message').hide();
});
$('[data-video-delete]').click(function(e) {
  $('#' + $(this).data('video-delete')).remove();
});
```

```css
.video-clickzone {
  min-height: 150px;
  border: 2px dashed #dddddd;
  background: white;
  padding: 20px 20px;
}
.video-clickzone:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.video-clickzone .ck-message {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2em 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="video-clickzone">
  <div class="ck-message">
    <div>
      <i class="fa fa-video-camera fa-5x"></i>
    </div>
    Click to add video
  </div>

  <ul id="videoSortable" class="list-unstyled list-inline"></ul>

</div>

<div class="modal bs-example-modal-md" id="videoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header bg-primary">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Add video</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>This is just an example, click on 'Add'</p>
        <div class="form-group" id="video-form">
          <label class="control-label" for="video-src">Video URL</label>
          <input type="url" id="video-src" class="form-control">
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="videoModalOK" data-actie="">Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That solved the issue! Based on your code I came up with this to also be able to use the delete link. `$('.video-clickzone').on("click", "img", function(evt){
        evt.stopPropagation();
        evt.preventDefault();
    });

    $('.video-clickzone').on('click', '[data-video-delete]', function(e){
        $('#'+$(this).data('video-delete')).remove();
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();

        sortVideos();
    });`

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the target for click event is your desired object or a children, just by doing this:

```
$('.video-clickzone').click(function(e) {
    if(e.target != this) return; //.video-clickzone was not clicked directly
    $videoModal.modal('show');
});
```

Anyway, you should also delegate event for dinamically added objects, so your code will look like

```
$(document).on('click', '.video-clickzone', (function(e) {
    if(e.target != this) return; //.video-clickzone was not clicked directly
    $videoModal.modal('show');
});
```